# generators in ES6: nested yields?

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator

Can anyone explain to me how this code works? (nested yields):

```
function* anotherGenerator(i) {
  yield i + 1;
  yield i + 2;
  yield i + 3;
}

function* generator(i){
  yield i;
  yield* anotherGenerator(i);
  yield i + 10;
}

var gen = generator(10);

console.log(gen.next().value); // 10
console.log(gen.next().value); // 11
console.log(gen.next().value); // 12
console.log(gen.next().value); // 13
console.log(gen.next().value); // 20
```

At first console.log() we get a value of 10 ,
after that 11 ..12...13...20... how does this nested yield work?

Comment: This is an example from MDN, right? That page links to [the page describing `yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`yield* anotherGenerator(i);` is basically a convenient shorthand for

```
for (var value of anotherGenerator(i)) {
  yield value;
}
```